# TYPO3 custom url pointing to folder

Tags: typo3

I'm trying to move my old TYPO3 website to WordPress. For migration I want to use cms2cms.

I need to upload custom php files and make them accessible on: http://domain/cms2cms/bridge.php.

Where should I upload that folder (I have tried uploading to fileadmin folder).

When I try that URL, I get redirected to page not found.

How can I set URL pointing to that folder?

I know nothing about TYPO3.

It's version is 6.1.7

Comment: there never was a version 6.3.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the team who built this Typo3 site originally (10 years ago).
They have moved the **cms2cms** forlder from **fileadmin** folder to *root* folder, which is outside the typo3 configuration.

***/pub/cust/site1/www/fileadmin/cms2cms --> /pub/cust/site1/www***

I found that I didn't even have access to that root folder.
So probably there was no way to configure url mapping in Typo3 storage.

Thanks to all for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

If you upload files to fileadmin, they're available at e.g. `http://domain/fileadmin/cms2cms/bridge.php`.

In case you really need the files to be in `http://domain/cms2cms/bridge.php` you need to do the upload via FTP or SSH. With the TYPO3 backend there is no way to store files on the root level.

Comment: I tried URL with fileadmin/ - Apache error. I also tried root folder with no luck. I'm reaching to whoever build this site for help.

Answer (score 1):

Since TYPO3 6.2(?) you can define `File Storage`s to access further folders than only /filadmin in the backend of TYPO3.

You need to define a file storage for your web root. Then you can create the folder `/cms2cms`. For easier handling (and better security) you then should delete that file storage ad create an own file storage for that folder only.

So you end up with two file storages in the TYPO3 backend you can access (if the general rights for that installation permit creating new folders in webroot)

Comment: My bad, it's version 6.1.7. I don't want to change definition of file storage (don't want to break the site), Where can I find that file storage settings, so I can find whre is file storage mapped to?

Comment: I'm not sure when `file storages` were introduced. maybe your Version already can handle it. 'file storages' are records in the root page of your page tree (id=0). and you should not change the default (1, fileadmin), but add further records. If it is not possible you stay with the option from Peter and use FTP or similar.